# Changing the impact of flag weight

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Why isn't flag weight tied to voting to close/reopen/delete/undelete votes?

It would seem logical that someone that who has a high flag weight should be able to cast these votes, as in many cases it would mean more community involvement in decisions that would otherwise be made by a moderator.

It would also mean that there would be more people that can cast delete/undelete votes (as of now there are 48 or so).

Comment: If that's what it takes to make people start using those tools more, rather than relying on flags alone, I'd surely support it

Comment: @IvoFlipse "Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted." ([source](http://superuser.com/privileges/moderator-tools)).